# Conversion of text which is in format CP037 to hexadecimal

Tags: java, encoding, hex, ebcdic

I have a text in the below format which is CP037  format and I want that to be converted to hexadecimal format in java.

Text1 - AGNSAÃ¦Ã»ÃÃÂÃÂµÂjÂqÂÂ Â Ã
Text2 - AGNSÂ²tÂÂ ÂÂÂµ.nÂZ|ÂÂÃÃ

First I thought of converting it to ascii and then to hexadecial, but the conversion is not happening properly

```
public class CP037ToASCII {

    public static String Tex (String ascii)
    {
        String hex = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < ascii.length(); i++) 
         {
             char ch = ascii.charAt(i);
             int in = (int)ch;
             String part = Integer.toHexString(in);
             hex += part; 
          }
         System.out.println(hex);
         return hex;
    }

public static String Tex (String ascii)
    {
        String hex = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < ascii.length(); i++) 
         {
             char ch = ascii.charAt(i);
             int in = (int)ch;
             String part = Integer.toHexString(in);
             hex += part; 
          }
         return hex;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
      {

         String encodedStr = "AGNSAÃ±AÂ¦Ã»ÃÃÂÃÂµÂjÂqÂÂÂÂ Â Ã";
         byte[] ebcByte = encodedStr.getBytes("Cp037");
         System.out.println("EBCDIC Byte " + ebcByte);

         String ascStr = new String(ebcByte, "ASCII");
         System.out.println("ASCII String " + ascStr);

         System.out.println ("String converted to hexadecimal");
         Tex(ascStr);

             System.out.println ("String converted to hexadecimal"); 
             System.out.println (Tex("AGNSA??A???????????j?q???? ? ?")); 

      }
}

could anyone please help
```

Comment: You already (incorrectly, likely) converted CP037 **bytes** to a String. At that point, a lot of things may have gone wrong already. You don't show your real source of CP037 data, but characters in a particular encoding should be represented as a `byte[]` or as `InputStream`/`OutputStream`. And then the question becomes: how do I show a `byte[]` in hexadecimal.

Comment: Thank you Erwin for the details. So first i need to convert the CP037 to array bytes and then to hexadecimal ? If so how do I convert the CP037 code to array bytes ?

Comment: @MJM no if the ebcdic data is in a File,read it as a stream. In the program you could do "1234".getBytes("Cp037") which should return {xF1, xF2, xF3, xF4} or you could just encode the array like  {xF1, xF2, xF3, xF4} (for "1234")

Comment: @BruceMartin - No it’s not a file , the values are present in a database table. I have to read those values and convert them to hexadecimal.

Comment: Read them from the table as bytes